# Git push looks for Change id even though already there

Tags: git

I have commit message containing change id (straight from a checkout from gerrit to my local machine).

```
commit bb4bfe6f068b4f21414610e28f9216ada2810310 (HEAD)
Author: xxxx<ccc.d.usman@ccc.com>
Date:   Thu Jan 18 12:11:55 2018 +0000

TORF-164239 ARE XYZ page to include extra columns

Change-Id: I6b79a8723acc629470582cfb8cac22495e282b4b
```

But when i try to push, it tells me that said commit message is not there.

```
$ git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
Counting objects: 533, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (292/292), done.
Writing objects: 100% (533/533), 55.17 KiB | 1.62 MiB/s, done.
Total 533 (delta 401), reused 264 (delta 213)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (401/401)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done
remote: (W) d40d4c1: commit subject >50 characters; use shorter first 
paragraph
remote: (W) d40d4c1: too many commit message lines longer than 72 
characters; manually wrap lines
remote: ERROR: [72fe4c9] missing Change-Id in commit message footer
remote:
remote: Hint: To automatically insert Change-Id, install the hook:
remote:   gitdir=$(git rev-parse --git-dir); scp -p -P 29418 
yyyyyy@gerrit.xyz.se:hooks/commit-msg ${gitdir}/hooks/
remote: And then amend the commit:
remote:   git commit --amend
remote:
To ssh://gerrit.zyz.se:29418/xyz/com.xyz.cifwk.diagmon/ddp
! [remote rejected]     HEAD -> refs/for/master ([72fe4c9] missing Change-Id 
in commit message footer)
error: failed to push some refs to 
'ssh://gerrit.xyz.se:29418/xyz/com.xyz.cifwk.diagmon/ddp'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the error message, you are trying to push a different commit `72fe4c9` that does not have the required change id in its commit message.

You can see the commits using `git log -p`, and fix the issue using `git rebase -i`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you ran `git pull` without `-r` or `--rebase` before you made `bb4bfe6f068b4f21414610e28f9216ada2810310` and a merge commit was created. It's most probably `72fe4c9`. A merge commit does not invoke `commit-msg` to generate a Change-Id. So you need to either generate a Change-Id for that merge commit `72fe4c9` or just rebase your local new non-merge commits onto the latest HEAD of the target branch:

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase FETCH_HEAD
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you, First pull:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

Then, try to push:

```
git push origin master
```